# Azure Cloud Shell blue and blank

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-shell

Azure cloud shell shows weird behavior most of the time. As shown in the image it remains blank. If we type the white courser moves. Sometimes we can see it all but when we execute a command the cursor goes up and remains among the text above. we have to clear screen to see the cursor again or to see what we type. Is there an alternative UI to cloud shell?
[image]

EDIT:
As per one of the answers below I tried another [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/get-started-azureps?view=azps-5.3.0). But that too gave the same error as given below. Frequency is less in this UI though.
[image]

Comment: incognito mode?

Comment: No I wasn't on incognito mode

Answer (score 1):

You can also go to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/get-started-azureps?view=azps-5.3.0) -> then click the `Try It` button:

[image]

**After login**, you can see the azure cloud shell screen:

[image]

**Or** if you still have the issue in azure portal, just click the `restart button` to reset the cloud shell:

[image]

Comment: restart button never solved it. but the link for an alternate screen is worth trying. Accepting it as answer for now.

Comment: that gave the same error too, edited my question to include this

Comment: @BlueClouds, which browser are you using? I'm using the latest version of Edge browser(Version 88.0.705.50). And could you please press F12 button of your browser to see if any error.

Comment: Firefox browser

Comment: @BlueClouds, can you try it in edge browser?